# Javascript - unicode not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, unicode

Whenever I run this code, the unicode converts as a question mark character.  It's supposed to change the "font" using unicode characters in `_font`.

`#ta` is a textarea
`#changer` is a `<select>` with options that are the names in `_font`

```
  var _font = {
  base:"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
  circled_neg:"",
  bold:"",
  bold_franktur:"",
  bold_italic:"",
  bold_script:"",
  outline:"ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ",
  mono:"",
  sans_serif:"",
  sans_bold:"",
  sans_italic:"",
  sans_bold_italic:"",
  squared:"",
  franktur:"",
  small_caps:"ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩqʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxyᴢᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩQʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxYᴢ",
};
$(function() {
  console.log(_font.franktur);
  var $ta = $("#ta"), $changer = $("#changer"), font = new Font(_font);

  $changer.change(function() {
    var val = $ta.val(), to = $changer.val();
    var str = font.convert(val, to);
    console.log(str);

  });
});
var Font = function(arr) {
  this.fontset = arr;
};
Font.prototype.convert = function(from, to) {
  var fromSet = this.getFont(from);
  var toSet = this.fontset[to];
  console.log(fromSet);
  console.log(toSet);
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0 ; i < from.length ; i++) {
    var ch = from.charAt(i);
    var j =  fromSet.indexOf(ch);
    console.log(j)
    if(j != -1) {
      ch = toSet.charAt(j);
    }
    console.log(ch);
    str += ch;
  }
  return str;
};
Font.prototype.getFont = function(text) {
  for(var i in this.fontset) {
    if(this.fontset[i].indexOf(text.charAt(0)) != -1) {
      var f = this.fontset[i];
      return f;
    }
  }
  return this.fontset.base;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some unicode symbols are stored as several symbols. So in fact your sets have different lengths. See the snippet:

```js
var _font = {
  base: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
  circled_neg: "",
  bold: "",
  bold_franktur: "",
  bold_italic: "",
  bold_script: "",
  outline: "ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ",
  mono: "",
  sans_serif: "",
  sans_bold: "",
  sans_italic: "",
  sans_bold_italic: "",
  squared: "",
  franktur: "",
  small_caps: "ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩqʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxyᴢᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩQʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxYᴢ",
};
$(function() {
  console.log(_font.base.length + ' <=> ' + _font.franktur.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And when you take `toSet.charAt(j);` sometimes it appears to be a half of the unicode symbol which shows as a `?`.

The solution is to store your sets as arrays. In the code snippet below I'm converting the sets  on the fly. But it would be better to make them Arrays in the `_font` declaration.

```js
var _font = {
  base: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
  circled_neg: "",
  bold: "",
  bold_franktur: "",
  bold_italic: "",
  bold_script: "",
  outline: "ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ",
  mono: "",
  sans_serif: "",
  sans_bold: "",
  sans_italic: "",
  sans_bold_italic: "",
  squared: "",
  franktur: "",
  small_caps: "ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩqʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxyᴢᴀʙᴄᴅᴇꜰɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴩQʀꜱᴛᴜᴠᴡxYᴢ",
};
$(function() {
  var $ta = $("#ta"),
    $changer = $("#changer"),
    font = new Font(_font);

  $changer.change(function() {
    var val = $ta.val(),
      to = $changer.val();
    var str = font.convert(val, to);
    console.log(str);

  });
});
var Font = function(arr) {
  this.fontset = arr;
};
Font.prototype.convert = function(from, to) {
  var fromSet = Array.from(this.getFont(from));
  var toSet = Array.from(this.fontset[to]);
  var str = "";
  for (var i of from) {
    var j = fromSet.indexOf(i);
    str += j > -1 ? toSet[j] : i;
  }
  return str;
};
Font.prototype.getFont = function(text) {
  for (var i in this.fontset) {
    if (this.fontset[i].indexOf(text.charAt(0)) != -1) {
      var f = this.fontset[i];
      return f;
    }
  }
  return this.fontset.base;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta">Some text for test purpose.</textarea>
<select id="changer">
<option>base</option>
<option>circled_neg</option>
<option>bold</option>
<option>bold_franktur</option>
<option>bold_italic</option>
<option>bold_script</option>
<option>outline</option>
<option>mono</option>
<option>sans_serif</option>
<option>sans_bold</option>
<option>sans_italic</option>
<option>sans_bold_italic</option>
<option>squared</option>
<option>franktur</option>
</select>
```